# ng-click used inside ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angularjs-ng-click

I'm hoping you can help me figure out how to merge my ng-click event into my code. I've been trying to figure it out all weekend. I found this ng-click event jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/09k8f5s4/97/ that I want to use inside my project.

I want users to be able to see the grid and simply click a box and have it switch between 'Y' and 'N', back and forth.

I have tried many ways of incorporating the ng-click event into my webpage. Here is a plunker I made to make it easy to share: http://plnkr.co/edit/eTf96oJLIjtM7UiB742e?p=preview

I guess I need to figure out how to define the scope differently to add my function?

Do I need to use a  to call the ng-click?

Do I need to add variables into my $scope.myData? Something like:

```
$scope.myData = [
        { time: "8:00am", monday: val, tuesday: val,
??????????????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `cellTemplate` for a column in column defination:

```
       { 
          field: 'monday', 
          displayName: 'Monday' ,
          cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-click="onClickFn(row.entity, col.field)">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div>',
          enableCellEdit: false
        }
```

Check this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6CUyNxZ8Hj6QIAC2Hh9X?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have played with this for a handful of hours in frustration. Appreciate it.